# Set onError method for Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set an `onError` method for the flutter framework, and am wondering if I can do the same for dart.

In the following example I have passed my own method `_onFlutterError` to be called when the Flutter framework catches an error..

```
FlutterError.onError = _onFlutterError;
```

I have noticed that some thrown errors in my flutter app do not get caught by flutter. For example throws that happen in code called my the http library I am using.

Is there a way I can set an method to be called on any potential thrown error?

Comment: You could try running all of your code within your own [error `Zone`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Zone/errorZone.html).